# uriBuilder.scheme not adding :// in the URL

Tags: android, android-intent, uribuilder

I am using `Uri Builder` to generate URL like following.

```
uriBuilder.scheme("https")
 .appendPath("test")
 .appendQueryParameter("code", "S256")
```

The output is `https:/test?code=S256` .

I need following output `https://test?code=S256`

If i add `uriBuilder.scheme("https://")` then it add `://` with `:/`

Comment: What is UriBuilder? This looks like a bug.

Comment: @TheWanderer : Uri.Builder uriBuilder = new Uri.Builder()

Comment: Yes, but what is the import? Where is this from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
uriBuilder.scheme("https")
.authority("test")
.appendQueryParameter("code", "S256")
```